# Flash to JQuery, solution?

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to switch an animation FLASH to an animation JQuery? I am actually using http://www.spritely.net/ the problem is IE.. With big animation IE is very **VERY** slow and we can't abuse it. I would like to know if there is any other pluging i could use and it is working with IE 7+.

Comment: The js rendering machine for IE 8- is very slow. You could use adobe edge but I don't think you will see much of improvement

Answer (score 0):

Google Lab is testing a tool, Swiffy, to convert Flash to HTML5. I don't know if it can help. Have a look at this website: http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/

**EDIT**: I just saw that you would like the solution to work for IE 7... My answer will not work I'm afraid.

Comment: I Already know Swiffy, i think this is a good project by Google! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Automatically converting might be very hard, but some combination of jQuery and Raphael should be able to do what you need, and will compatible with all IEs (even IE6!)